Trouble Building Wheel for llama-cpp-python: CMake Configuration Failed
I'm trying to install a package that relies on building a wheel for llama-cpp-python from a pyproject.toml file. However, during the build process, I encounter the following error:
Building wheel for llama-cpp-python (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for llama-cpp-python (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [20 lines of output]
*** scikit-build-core 0.8.2 using CMake 3.29.2 (wheel)
*** Configuring CMake...
2024-04-14 01:31:00,685 - scikit_build_core - WARNING - Can't find a Python library, got libdir=None, ldlibrary=None, multiarch=None, masd=None
loading initial cache file C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9m_kappd\build\CMakeInit.txt
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  Running

   'nmake' '-?'

  failed with:

   no such file or directory


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

*** CMake configuration failed
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for llama-cpp-python
Failed to build llama-cpp-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for llama-cpp-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have ensured that GCC, G++, and CMake are installed, and I've set the necessary environment variables. Despite this, the CMake configuration seems to be failing, specifically in recognizing the C and C++ compilers.
Here are the steps I've taken:

Installed GCC, G++, and CMake.
Set the necessary environment variables.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
